# Computer runs Python 3.8 by default, even though 3.9 is installed

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8, macos-big-sur, python-3.9

I just installed Python 3.9.5 on my computer (Mac OS, Big Sur). But by default, when I try to run Python in my terminal, it will only run 3.8.5. This is what happens:

```
% python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

If I try `% python3 -V`  I get:
`Python 3.8.5`. Similarly, for `% pip -V`, I get:

```
pip 21.1.1 from /Users/max/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

How do I change the default for Python and pip to 3.9?

Comment: is this a virtunal env or default we are talking about?

Comment: *Before you do anything: Don't mess with the Python version that was installed by default. It might break important stuff.*
Now see if you can call `python3.9`!

Comment: @KlausD. python3.9 works

Comment: @Avinash_cdns default

Comment: conda install python=3.9

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would suggest you to use [pipenv](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-on-macos) or [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/) **always** when you need to use specific version of python in some project. These tools are built to let you use whatever python you want *on a project (virtualenv) level*. Because, for example, what are you going to do if you'll have a couple of projects on your machine, that are running on a different versions of python?

Beside of that, I guess, you could use an alias pointing to a specific version you need in a `~/.profile` or smth.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.9" >> ~/.zshrc
# for Bash
$ echo "alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3.9" >> ~/.bashrc

$ echo "alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3" >> ~/.zshrc 
# for Bash
$ echo "alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3" >> ~/.bashrc
```